# save or forward texts from an iPod touch

Tags: ipod-touch, messages, text

Is it possible to save or forward texts from an iPod touch?

This is for a kid who is being bullied by a class-mate, and I want to keep a record of the texts sent.

Comment: There is no SMS on an iPod touch. Which app are you using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have the native Messages app (assuming you have a compatible iPod Touch, and are using that app), automatically forward texts. You can, however, manually forward texts: open the Messages app, open a thread, tap Edit, tap the check boxes for the texts to forward, tap Forward, then enter the recipient.

Unless the user deletes the messages, they aren't deleted automatically. As a result, they are saved in a way. However, it is very easy for the user to delete the messages, and once deleted, there is no way to recover them.

Answer (score 1):

A rather easy way is to just take screenshots of the offending messages and syncing/mailing them to your computer for future reference.

Comment: definitely a good option if there's no alternative, but I prefer to have the entire stream, rather than just one message.

Comment: PhoneView http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/ is a Mac app to let you save out your text messages as PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I take screenshots to save my text messages. I also use the desktop program [decipher text message](http://www.deciphertools.com) when I need to save an entire conversation history to my computer for archiving. The software is easy to use and effective. If you just need to save one text though, a screenshot might be simpler for your needs!

Answer (score 0):

PhoneView http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/ is a Mac app to
let you save out your text messages as PDF files.